# Does anyone know if there's a command parser for Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Does anyone know a parser that can parse commands from the format:

`!command argument one, argument two`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not write your own? If you want this format in particular, just do something like the following:

```js
let parser = function(msg){
    return msg.replace(command, "").split(",").map(e => e.trim());
};
```

In this case I first remove the command prefix (`!command`), then split all arguments into an array and finally trim the spaces around the arguments.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/k3sxrcfh/